# How to just display one field from the form in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to display just one field from my form that I have created but I am getting 'Could not parse the remainder:' error

Here is my forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
     model = Product
     fields = ('prod_name', 'company', 'quantity', 'price', 'units', 'prod_type')
```

Here is my html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
 <div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
        <br>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.name=='units' %}
            <div class ="form-form row">
                <label for="id_{{field.name}}" class="col-2 col-form-label">{{field.label}}</label>
                <div class ="col-10">
                    {{field}}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Update Sales</button>
    </form>         
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I just want to display units in my webpage for this module that I am creating

Comment: Why not make a form with only one field? This looks more safe.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank You...your method worked!

Answer (score 3):

I think you try to solve the problem on the wrong level. You can just construct a form with one field:

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class UnitProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('units',)
```

If you need the other form as well, you can just create an extra one, with a different name, like here `UnitProductForm`.

Using a form with a subset of fields is not only *easier* to render. The form will *not* make modifications to fields of a model object if these are not specified, even if these items are passed in a (forged) POST request. So it makes it more safe to use as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only prod_name field then you can do it:
{
from django import forms
from .models import *

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
     model = Product
     fields = ('prod_name')

}

Answer (score 0):

Displaying just one field can be controlled from the templates like:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
 <div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.units.label_tag }} /*Shows the label for the input field */
        {{ form.units }} /*Shows the input field */
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Update Sales</button>
    </form>         
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is from the official documentation, found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

Note that you will have to handle creation of the object in the backend, if you choose to display only certain fields like this.